# Using MVVM Pattern Binding WPF Grid to a WCF Service

Tags: wcf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

[image]I am trying to bind the data returned from WCF service to a grid in WPF using MVVM. The same works when i use the logic of WCF service in view model.

**Code Behind:**

```
this.DataContext = new SampleViewModel();
```

**View/XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="Sample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
 <Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Students}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Address" Binding="{Binding Address}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
 </Grid>
</Window>
```

**View Model:**

```
public List<Student> Students {
        get {
            var service = new StudentServiceClient();
            var students = new List<Student>(service.GetStudents());
            return students;
        }
    }
```

**IStudentService:**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IStudentService {
    [OperationContract]
    IEnumerable<Student> GetStudents();
}

[DataContract]
public class Student {
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

**StudentService.svc:**

```
public class StudentService : IStudentService {
    public IEnumerable<Student> GetStudents() {
        var students = new List<Student>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            students.Add(new Student {
                Name = "Name" + i,
                ID = i,
                Address = "Address" + 1
            });
        }

        return students;
    }
}
```

When i run the app, i dont see ant records in the grid..

Comment: fixed the issue.. Was missing the DataMember attribute from the data Contract

Answer (score 3):

```
public List<Student> Students {
    get {
        var service = new StudentServiceClient();
        var students = new List<Student>(service.GetStudents());
        return students;
    }
}
```

Every time the Students property is used/read this code will connect to the server and retrieve the students. That will be too slow.

Load the Students in the constructor of the ViewModel (or in a separate method/command) and return this collection from the getter.

The reasons why your solution doesn't work can be:

1. List doesn't notify the View of changes of the collection; use ObservableCollection instead.
2. When the Students property changes (`var students = new List<Student>(service.GetStudents());`) there is no signal to the View that the property has changed; Implement INotifyPropertyChanged on the ViewModel.
3. Make sure the Service returns data.

Comment: +1; @Arihant: I'm thinking WPF is making some optimizations based on your read-only non-observable list, and not refreshing the empty view.  If moving the WCF call to the constructor and exposing `Students` as an `ObservableCollection` doesn't solve the problem, you could also try adding a setter (tho I don't know that this is required or will help).

Answer (score 0):

Are there any binding errors? Or maybe there is a serviceside problem, and the service returns no entries. Did you debug / breakpoint the property's getter and check the result?

Comment: When debug from the service it shows the correct results. However in VM, it shows the correct count but the collection shows Extension Data's members as null.

Comment: What do you mean with Extension Data? Of what type is the collection that gets returned? You can change the datatype by right click the servicereference and choose config.

Comment: It is not showing the properties being returned correctly from the service..Screnshot attached to the question